# Samsung Galaxy s3 mini continuously rebooting

Tags: factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I woke up to find My Samsung Galaxy s3 mini asking me to select a language and time and sign into my Samsung account, like it was a brand new phone. As I tried to do this it kept rebooting. eventually I managed to sign in, but it continues to reboot every minute or so and a few of my widgets are missing. After researching I uninstalled the Samsung push app but it keeps going back to the sign in start page, but it reboots before I can sign in and there is no way to skip it.

I have removed my battery, SIM card and SD card, but it is still happening. I also tried a factory reset, but every time I click on it me phone restarts and nothing has changes.

Does anyone know what is going on or what I can do to stop it rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

First method-

- Reset the device (press and hold POWER button for 8-10 seconds).

Second method-

1. Press and hold VOLUME UP and Home(center) button, then press Power until the phone vibrates. Wait until you see the Android logo then release all the buttons.
2. Select Wipe data/Factory reset with VOLUME DOWN key, press Power (right hand-side).
3. Select YES -- this deletes all user data.
4. After format, press Power again to reboot phone (select reboot system now).
5. If your device is frozen and unresponsive, press and hold Samsung Galaxy S3 hard reset for 8-10 seconds. The device will reboot automatically.

Third method-

1. Factory format entering sgs3 mini format code. Enter *2767*3855#.

*Note - Warning! All your data including contacts, messages etc. will be lost! Copy all your necessary data/Contacts/Messages etc. to SIM or make backup to your PC before full reset! Take out SIM card before full reset. Source: [Hard-reset.com](http://www.hard-reset.com/samsung-galaxy-s3-mini-hard-reset.html).*

Comment: Thank you. It took me a ,one time to save all my contacts to my sim (as it kept resetting) but eventually the second method worked well!

Comment: You mind marking this as answer if your problem is solved ;-)

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue
Solution: battery replacement.